# ascii characters in my string

Tags: jquery

I have a string that I'm trying to send over to my server code. I am getting a lot of these characters in the data - `�`. Do I need to serialize the data or what? I'm using utf-8 encoding but that doesn't fix it. I think that something is happening to my data on the JQuery side. How do I fix this?

Here is what my JQ looks like.

```
var id = $('#id').val();
var dataString = 'id='+ id;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http...",
  data: dataString,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
  ...
```

---

Here is a sample string:
`%ca 32d?

This string then becomes `�32d?` with UTF-8 and `Ê32d?`with iso-8859-1

---

**EDIT:**
I noticed that this encoding issue only happens when the string begins with `%ca`. All others seem to work as expected.

Comment: Can you give an example of the string? It could be anything from it being a unicode character or a character that can't be displayed in whatever font you are printing it with.

Comment: I deleted my answer because that probably wasn't it. The question is what encoding your data is in - just changing the PHP headers won't suffice. You should definitely show an example here, and maybe some code. This can also happen if you double-encode things, like when calling `utf8_encode()` on data that is already UTF8 encoded.

Comment: I should also add that before I decided to use JQ to stop page refreshes, that everything worked great when the page refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

%xx in HTTP protocol is an encoded character, which the server will decode for you, even if you don't want to. You should either url encode your string before sending or replace every % with %25, which is the encoded equivalent of %. It's the same concept as with the \ characters. If you have \n in a string the engine will interpret it as a newline, even if n is part of a word for example.

Hope that helps.